# Python, Float Recording Text File, Loading Floats and average them

Tags: python, floating

i have biological floats and want to save them in a Text file, and then load and make average them. This Floats about :

```
0.12
0.23
0.30
0.21
..
..
..
```

This will be saved in Text file.

Average of Floats will be showed in Label.

Comment: How could i write and then load these Floats in a text file . Finally how can i make average them

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and be sure to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: how are these numbers generated? Do you read them one at a time or do you have a list of them?

Comment: Read one at time.

Answer (score 1):

In order to save the floats to a text file, you need to convert them to a string. We convert the list of floats to a list of strings, then join them with a space symbol, which will be the separator and then save the file.
In order to read a text file and make that a new list of floats we need to do the same operations but reversed.

About the label, I don't know what GUI framework you are using.

code:

```
list_of_floats=[0.12, 0.23, 0.30, 0.21]

def save(path,l):
    with open(path,'w') as file:
        file.write(' '.join(map(str,l)))

def load(path):
        with open(path,'r') as file:
            return list(map(float,file.read().split()))

save('file.txt',list_of_floats)
new_list=load('file.txt')
print(sum(new_list)/len(new_list))
```

Comment: Thanks igor, i want to print average of them

Comment: I have edited the code. The average is the sum of the list divided by it's length

Comment: if floats are not stable, how could we edit codes? For example : we have list_of_floats=[0.12, 0.23, 0.30, 0.21], if floats come in a second with irregular. E.g : 0.12  0.13.    ...... always..

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

this is a robust code:

```
import numpy as np
import os
x = np.arange(12).reshape(4, 3)
x=x/23
print("Original array:")
print(x)
header = 'col1 col2 col3'
np.savetxt('temp.txt', x, fmt="%1.3f", header=header)
print("After loading, content of the text file:")
result = np.loadtxt('temp.txt')
print(result)
print('Lets do a calculation on it :')
print(sum(result)/len(result))
```